# How to make an interface method return another interface?

Tags: go, interface

I have an interface with one method that returns a slice of another interface. Here is a simple representation:

```
type Garage interface {
    AllCars() []Car
}

type Car interface {
    Name() string
}
```

I have also made an implementation for this:

```
type MyGarage struct{}

func (g MyGarage) AllCars() []MyCar {
    return make([]MyCar, 0)
}

type MyCar struct {
    name string
}

func (c MyCar) Name() string {
    return c.name
}
```

Now in my test I have made a function:

```
func TestAllCars(t *testing.T) {
    var garage Garage
    garage = new(mygarage.MyGarage)
    cars := garage.AllCars()
    fmt.Println(cars)
}
```

And Go complains that MyGarage does not implement the Garage interface, which I understand, but did not expect, because MyCar does implement Car, so it should not have been an issue to me.

```
cannot use new(mygarage.MyGarage) (type *mygarage.MyGarage) as type Garage in assignment:
    *mygarage.MyGarage does not implement Garage (wrong type for AllCars method)
        have AllCars() []mygarage.MyCar
        want AllCars() []Car
```

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit after comments

I tried changing the method to returning just a single car as to avoid the issues around slices of interfaces, yet it still complains. Just for the sake of me wanting to understand what is going on. Since `MyCar` implements `Car` I did not expect the following error:

```
*mygarage.MyGarage does not implement Garage (wrong type for GetCar method)
    have GetCar() mygarage.MyCar
    want GetCar() Car
```

I believe the issue is being a strongly typed return type, MyCar is not a Car, but it should be possible to cast it to one, yet Go does not accept that as a valid implementation for the interface Garage?

Comment: `MyGarage.AllCars()` must return `[]Car`, `[]MyCar` is not the same.

Comment: Yup, but that would create a dependency that I am trying to avoid if possible. Since `MyGarage` can implement `Garage` without a dependency, why can `MyCar` not do the same for `Car`?

Comment: This is because a slice of interface is not an interface see the following https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

Comment: Note that the signature of a function/method is its type. For type `T` to implement interface `I`, type `T` must implement the methods of `I`, and the methods' types/signatures must match *verbatim*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with slices of interface not being interfaces, that being said I think that the below gives you what you want.

https://play.golang.org/p/qg0NQNCIjx7

```
type Garage interface {
    AllCars() []Car
}

type Car interface {
    Name() string
}

type MyGarage struct{

}

func (g MyGarage) AllCars() []Car {
    x := []Car{MyCar{}}
    return x
}

type MyCar struct {
    name string
}

func (c MyCar) Name() string {
    return c.name
}

func main() {
    var garage Garage
    garage = MyGarage{}
    cars := garage.AllCars()
    fmt.Println(cars)
}
```

Comment: Yes that is a similar suggestion as icza gave in the comments, but considering that Garage and MyGarage are in different packages this would create a dependency from package[MyGarage] to package[Garage] (to have access to the interface Car) Since this dependency is not needed for MyGarage to implement Garage, I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: I guess you are correct but surely the upper level code should have the interfaces within and your packages should implement that interface, this is because the code that will orchestrate this needs to know more then the lower implementations, with that said this then becomes more of a question of if your package interface design and layout is correct

Comment: Also, I will go back to my comment about slices of interfaces are not interfaces, with the above code we are still not talking in pure interfaces exactly we are actually talking about slices, in the methods you are returning slices that contain interfaces as elements as the document I linked helps with, so when you are saying that it is not accepting the abstraction that is actually not what is going on, it is not accepting the static type of slice that contains interface elements, please read the doc above it explains what I mean better then I can give in a comment.